# Problems with installation of owl carousel

Tags: javascript, html, owl-carousel

Hey guys I am new at web development and wanted to install owl carousel on the page but nothing happens. Here is the code I have:

```
<section class="showcase">
    <div class="owl-carousel">
        <div><img src="./9781471407956.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="./9781471407956.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="./9781471407956.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="./9781471407956.jpg" alt=""></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Then I have included the links in inside head tag as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./OwlCarousel2-2.3.4/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./OwlCarousel2-2.3.4/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
```

Finally, I included the javascript codes just before closing body:

```
<script src="./OwlCarousel2-2.3.4/docs/assets/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./OwlCarousel2-2.3.4/dist/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
});
```

I really need your help

Comment: is css and js file is success to load? why `./` not `../` ? and make sure you follow this example [link](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-installation.html)

Comment: Check in console if `$.fn.owlCarousel` isn't undefined, or check if you have any `404 errors` in network tab

Answer (score 0):

```
var owl = jQuery('.owl-carousel');
            owl.owlCarousel({
                items: 1,
                margin: 10,
                autoplay: true,
                autoPlay: 3000,
                nav: false,
                dots: false,
                autoplayTimeout: 3000,
                autoplayHoverPause: true,
                loop: true,
});
```

Then in style include

```
.owl-item {
   float:left
}
```

Comment: so I have put the following code: $(document).ready(function(){
        var owl = jQuery('.owl-carousel');
            owl.owlCarousel({
                items: 1,
                margin: 10,
                autoplay: true,
                autoPlay: 3000,
                nav: false,
                dots: false,
                autoplayTimeout: 3000,
                autoplayHoverPause: true,
                loop: true,
});
      }); Is this correct code?